# 19F NMR line spectra

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I am trying to figure out the NMR spectra of F<sub>3</sub>P-BH<sub>3</sub>

I am solving this out using 2nI+1 rule. 
 I<sub>P</sub> = 1/2 and I<sub>B</sub> = 3/2

Hence for this compound,

> (2nI<sub>P</sub>+1)(2nI<sub>B</sub>+1) = (2x1X1/2+1)(2X1X3/2+1) =
> (2)(4) = 8 lines (quadraplet of doublet)

This is what I came up with, it would be great if you could correct me if I'm wrong. Trying to solve few problems before the exam =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have got the calculation right. However, I would also consider the coupling between F and H because coupling through 3 bonds is also usually visible. So, each of your 8 lines will be split into four by the H-atoms.

That will be the major part of the spectrum. You would also get weak signals with a different splitting pattern due to the other isotope of boron ($\ce{^10B, I=3}$, abundance=20%).